# Javascript, accessing and modifying a css rule after having inserted it by insertRule()

Tags: javascript, css, dom, stylesheet

I am thinking about the best way to dynamically add and remove css rules.

*I don't want to use the deleteRule() function since it requires an index that cannot be stored (in the sense that if I add a rule, the index of the previously inserted rule may change)

Then, ideally I would like to add a rule for which I also have the reference, so that I cannot eliminate it, but at least I'd be able to change it. However, I'm afraid this cannot be done.

- The question then is, is this code feasible?

https://jsfiddle.net/b4t3z5w4/1/

```
 var rule = ".item_1 { display: inline;}";
 var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];
 var rules = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules;
 var myrule = ".item0 {display:visible;}";
 var mycssrule = stylesheet.insertRule(myrule,rules.length);

 myrule.style.display = 'none'; // doesn't work (it is just a string)
 mycssrule.style.display = 'none'; // doesn't work (insertRule only returns I guess a true)
```

(I know I can get the css rule by parsing the cssRules and finding the rule and storing then the reference, I just wanted to know if is there a way to do it through insertRule(), it seems it should be possible)

Comment: Can you tell us why you are trying to do this? Possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: I need to change the display property of a class that has to be defined dynamically. But I could define (statically) let's say 40 classes (.item_0, .item_1, ...) (the 40 should then not be reached), then parse the css, store the rules and later on dynamically change the rules. Or I could dynamically add the rules and if they have been already added, just access them and change the property. For this 2nd approach I needed to know how to access them, and if I had to parse the css sheet again then it didn't seem to be a good solution. Now that I can store the reference, I think I'm good to go

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than what I thought, I can select the rule since I have the index

https://jsfiddle.net/b4t3z5w4/2/

```
var rule = ".item_1 { display: inline;}";
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];
var rules = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules;
var myrule = ".item0 {display:visible;}";
var i = rules.length;
stylesheet.insertRule(myrule,rules.length);
var mycssrule = rules[i];
mycssrule.style.width = '80px';
console.log(mycssrule);
```